# Laravel: blade foreach looping bootstrap columns

Tags: php, laravel, loops, foreach, laravel-5.3

I have a foreach loop and inside that contains html with bootstrap columns.

```
@foreach($address as $add)
    <div class="col-md-6">
        Some data
    </div>
@endforeach
```

However, bootstrap requires the row div before creating columns, placing that straight in to the foreach loop would create a row div for each col-md-6. I want to know how I can throw in the row div, skip the next loop throwing in only the closing div tag. And then repeat that process.

Example output where the loops 4 times:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        Some data
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        Some data
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        Some data
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        Some data
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

As an alternative to Alexey Mezenin's answer you could use `array_chunk` instead. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

```
@foreach(array_chunk($address, 2) as $chunk)
    <div class="row">
        @foreach($chunk as $add)
            <div class="col-md-6">
                Some data
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
@endforeach
```

I personally find the the above a little more readable.

Alternatively, if `$address` is a collection you could do `$address->chunk(2)` instead of `array_chunk($address, 2)`.

If you want to change the amount of columns you have you would simply need to change the `2` to be however many columns you want.

Comment: This is an elegant way to do it. Thanks.

Comment: @SaadSuri You're absolute right. I've already got that in my answer though ;)

Comment: Sorry I didn't see that part. I was already amazed by answer so forgot to read the remaining part :)

Comment: @SaadSuri It's alright. I didn't realise it there straight away either :)

Comment: when I used ``$add->name`` it shows me error of `` try to get property  non-object `` !!

Comment: @MahdiSafari That would suggest to me that `$add` is not an object. Try using  `$add['name']` instead.

Answer (score 8):

You can use Laravel chunk in the blade template.

```
@foreach($products->chunk(3) as $items)
<div class="row">
   @foreach($items as $item)
   <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">
      <a href="#">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ 'uploads/'.$item->product_image_url }}" alt="">
      </a>
      <h3>
         <a href="/view-product-details/{{ $item->id }}">{{ $item->product_name }}</a>
      </h3>
      <p>{{ str_limit($item->product_description, 121) }}</p>
   </div>
   @endforeach
</div>
@endforeach
```

Copied from the [blogpost](http://busyprogrammersguide.blogspot.com/2017/07/laravel-54-bootstrap-row-class-for.html).

Answer (score 6):

Use [the `$loop` variable](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#the-loop-variable):

```
<div class="row">
    @foreach($address as $add)
        <div class="col-md-6">
            Some data
        </div>
        @if ($loop->iteration % 2 == 0)
            </div>
            <div class="row">
        @endif
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Comment: My whole site breaks and I get a [Vue warn]: Templates should only be responsible for mapping the state to the UI. Avoid placing tags with side-effects in your templates, such as <script>.

Comment: @ThomasCharlesworth I didn't place any tags like `<script>`. It's standard Blade template code. Please explain what are you trying to tell?

Comment: I left out the first div outside the foreach, I dont know why but this causes the site to break along with the vue warning. Thanks for the solution!