# Looping data which contains 3 column each row

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, bootstrap-4

My problem is divide 3 columns each row
image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/4phtb.jpg

```
<div id="list-product">
                <div class="row">       
                @foreach($products as $product)
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                        <a href="{{URL::route('products',['id'=>$product->id])}}">
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="wrap-img-product">
                                    <img src="{{asset($product->gambar)}}" alt="" class="card-img-top">
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 class="card-title">{{$product->name}}</h5>
                                    <p class="card-text">Rp{{number_format($product->harga_jual)}}</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                @endforeach
                </div>
            </div>
```

So, i want each tag row contains 3 column,

Comment: can you show us the image of what you want to do exactly? or can you explain more?

Comment: You want to use a modulus condition on the $index provided by the foreach loop?  Or an `array_chunk()` solution?

Comment: ok, maybe i will tried it first

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel: blade foreach looping bootstrap columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41650670/laravel-blade-foreach-looping-bootstrap-columns).

Comment: oh sorry,  I'm not careful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just chunk your data into sets of 3 and add a nested loop to iterate each set's data.

```
foreach (array_chunk($products, 3) as $set) {
    echo '<div class="row">';
        foreach ($set as $product) {
            echo '<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">';
                ...
            echo '</div>';
        }
   echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: thank before, i just finished