# Adding multiple div to a foreach loop - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, for-loop

I am new to Laravel. I am trying a loop through a multiple div and struck in between. I want to wrap a div with multiple columns in it.

```
@foreach($products as $product)
<div>
   <div class="row">
       @foreach($products as $product)
        <div class="col-md-4">
          {{image}} 
        </div>

       @endforeach
   </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

It's not printing the expected output. my expected output should be like.

```
<div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">image1</div>
        <div class="col-md-4">image2</div>
        <div class="col-md-4">image3</div>
     </div>
</div>

<div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">image4</div>
        <div class="col-md-4">image5</div>
        <div class="col-md-4">image6</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I print div properly with the above formate?

Comment: Why are you using another loop inside with same variable `$products`?
Single loop is enough to get the desired output.

Comment: its a code for the dynamic slider. I want to repeat through  loop to print   <div class="cold-md-4"></div> 3 times for each row.

Comment: What are you getting as output?

Comment: any idea how can I do this?

Comment: what is your current output

Comment: as of your question . I can Understand that You have a Slider and Each Slider Contanis the 3 images and you may have the multiple Sliders . Am i right

Comment: @Manojkiran.A yes

Comment: @Manojkiran.A I have updated my code.

Comment: Can you please post your `dd($products)` before your loop?

Comment: @party-ring ok. sure

Comment: @party-ring https://ibb.co/PjfjyDq

Comment: @Anusha Where is your Current Output

Comment: @Manojkiran.A I have tried all the answers but it displays many div inside a single row. I just want to print 3 div per each row.

Comment: could anyone resolve this?

Comment: @Anusha I posted an answer.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41650670/laravel-blade-foreach-looping-bootstrap-columns it may help @Anusha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Collection Chunks:

```
@foreach($products->chunk(3) as $chunk)
   <div class="row">
       @foreach($chunk as $product)
        <div class="col-md-4">
          YOUR IMAGE HERE 
        </div>
       @endforeach
   </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: I will try this

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
<div class="row">
    @for($i = 1; $i <= len($products); $i++)
            <div class="col-md-4">
              Title: {{$products[$i-1]->title }}
            </div>  
      @if($i%3===0)
        </div>  <div class="row">
      @endif
    @endfor
 </div>
```

Comment: does product always has 3 images?

Comment: $product has many images, but I want to print 3 images per row.

Comment: Is your **$projects** variable a simple array or an instance of **\Illuminate\Support\Collection**? (You could check it with var_dump). Also which variable contains the images for those products?

Comment: @KishoreKadiyala its not working. Undefined offset: 9 (View: /Projects/dailyharvest/resources/views/products.blade.php)

Answer (score -1):

```
@for($i = 0; $i < count($products); $i++)
<div>
   <div class="row">
       @foreach($products as $product)
        <div class="col-md-4">
          {{image}} 
        </div>

       @endforeach
   </div>
</div>
@endfor
```

Comment: it creates multiple infinite `col-md-4` inside a single row, i just want 3 `col-md-4` div  per row