# Dynamically create divs in Laravel blade using foreach

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have an object returned from controller to the blade using compact.
In my blade file I am using this to print the values

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-6"> <!-- This must regenerate to print next 4 entries-->
    <ul class="list_teachers">
        @php
            $length=count((array)$facility_details);
        @endphp
        @foreach($facility_details as  $key=>$value)
        @if(($key!='id')&&($key!='college_id')&&($key!='updated_at')&&($key!='created_at')&&($value!=0))
            <li class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                <a>
                <figure><img src="{{asset('assets/img/'.$key.'.png')}}" alt=""></figure>
                    <p>{{$key}}</p></a>
            </li>
        @endif
        @endforeach                                 
    </ul>
</div>
```

This code is working fine, but what I want to achieve is when four iterations of
`@foreach($facility_details as  $key=>$value)` happens, the loop should break to create another
`<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">` i.e a whole new `<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">` should be generated and **foreach** should begin with count of **4** to print next four entries.

Comment: You need to add another for or foreach loop for the main div

Comment: @dev_mustafa yes, but I have no idea how how to break it after four iterations also how to start over from the next iterations

Comment: Loops can have counters, or you can create your own; when the counter is or exceeds 4, create a div and reset the counter. Or, if you can't reset the counter, check if it's evenly divisible by 4 (using `%` modulus operator)

Comment: @TimLewis It's better and easier to use ```array_chunk```

Comment: @MohammadHosseini It's an alternative; "better" and "easier" are both subjective/opinionated terms though. Thank you for posting an answer, but it's beneficial for all options to be shown.

Comment: you can check the Loop variable: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#the-loop-variable

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41650670/laravel-blade-foreach-looping-bootstrap-columns/41650927#41650927

Comment: @TimLewis I agree with showing all the ways. Thank you for your attention dude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to achieve

```
               @foreach($facility_details as $key => $value)
                            @if (($loop->index % 4 == 0)||($loop->index == 0))
                                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                                <ul class="list_teachers">
                            @endif
                                @if(($key!='id')&&($key!='college_id')&&($key!='updated_at')&&($key!='created_at')&&($value!=0))
                                <li>
                                    <a>
                                        <figure><img src="{{asset('assets/img/'.$key.'.png')}}" alt=""></figure>
                                        <p>{{$key}}</p>
                                   </a>
                                 </li>
                                @endif
                              @if (($loop->index % 4 == 3)&&($loop->index > 0))   
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                  @endif
                @endforeach
```

This loop shows four entries inside outer `<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">` and then closes the `</div>` , Re-creates it and the process goes on.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in some ways:

**1-Use `array_chunk`**

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

```
@foreach(array_chunk($facility_details, 4) as $chunk)
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <ul class="list_teachers">

            @foreach($chunk as $key=>$value)
            @if(($key!='id')&&($key!='college_id')&&($key!='updated_at')&&($key!='created_at')&&($value!=0))
            <li class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                <a>
                <figure><img src="{{asset('assets/img/'.$key.'.png')}}" alt=""></figure>
                    <p>{{$key}}</p></a>
            </li>
            @endif
            @endforeach 

        </ul>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

**Note:** if $facility_details is a collection you could do `$facility_details->chunk(4)` instead of `array_chunk($facility_details, 4)`

**2- Use [the `$loop` variable](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#the-loop-variable)**

```
@foreach($facility_details as $key => $value)
    @if ($loop->iteration % 4 == 0)
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <ul class="list_teachers">
    @endif

        @if(($key!='id')&&($key!='college_id')&&($key!='updated_at')&&($key!='created_at')&&($value!=0))
        <li class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
            <a>
            <figure><img src="{{asset('assets/img/'.$key.'.png')}}" alt=""></figure>
                <p>{{$key}}</p></a>
        </li>
        @endif

    @if ($loop->iteration % 4 == 0)   
        </ul>
    </div>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: @pyrogrammer Can you write ```dd($chunk)``` inside first foreach and tell the result please?

Comment: Call to undefined method stdClass::chunk() this is what i get.

Comment: @pyrogrammer sorry I edited my cm, please check it again.

Comment: the chunk() method is not working, no benefit of writing dd($chunk) as it is showing error in ```@foreach($facility_details->chunk(4) as $chunk)```   too few arguments to function Builder::chunk()

Comment: @pyrogrammer I have added another way too.